# How to get 'hover' and 'active' states working with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I have 3 menu items in a header at the top of my website (it's not live at the moment so I can't provide a link - sorry). The 3 'buttons' are not buttons in the CSS buttons sense - they're text rendered to images (Not ideal, I know but they look pretty, so...).

Anyway, each image contains differing versions: 1 for the default appearance, 1 for mouseover and another for onclick/active. The html and CSS I'm using so far looks like this:

HTML

```
<li>
    <a id="About" class="button" href="About Us.cshtml">About Us</a>
</li>
<li style="margin-left: 30px;">
    <a id="Services" class="button" href="Services.cshtml">Services</a>
</li>
<li style="margin-left: 30px;">
    <a id="Contact" class="button" href="Contact Us.cshtml">Contact Us</a>
</li>
```

CSS

```
#About {background: url(../Buttons/About.png) no-repeat 0 0; width: 87px;}
#Services {background: url(../Buttons/Services.png) no-repeat 0 0; width: 112px;}
#Contact {background: url(../Buttons/Contact.png) no-repeat 0 0; width: 117px;}
a.button {height: 20px; display: inline-block;}
a.button:hover {background-position: 0 -20px;}
a.button:active {background-position: 0 -40px;}
```

For one reason or another, the 'hover' and 'active' states are having no effect. I note that if I define classes for each of the buttons instead of id's, it works fine - but this makes no sense to me. The buttons each have their own image and widths and so are unique (which is why I've given them id's rather than classes).

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong? I'm new to all this so any explanations will need to be in laymen's terms.

Comment: Please try to replicate the issue in jsfiddle. You'll get quicker and better answers.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of CSS specificity! Read this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: @ Gurpreet Singh - Thanks, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: @Scott Brown - Many thanks for the link. I'll have a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your ID selectors are more specific than your class + pseudoselector combination. But if you don't specify the position in the ID selector, you'll be fine. EG:

```
#About {background-image: url(../Buttons/About.png); width: 87px;}
#Services {background-image: url(../Buttons/Services.png); width: 112px;}
#Contact {background-image: url(../Buttons/Contact.png); width: 117px;}
a.button {height: 20px; display: inline-block; background-repeat: no-repeat}
a.button:hover {background-position: 0 -20px;}
a.button:active {background-position: 0 -40px;}
```

Comment: Aaaaaah, ok. I was using 'background: url...' and this was overriding the 'background-position' attribute in the class selector - so now that I've changed it to 'background-image: url...', there's no longer a conflict. and I guess having 'no-repeat' in the id selectors was adding to the problem. Correct? Thanks for your help. I think I understand it a little better now.

Comment: That's exactly right. CSS can be a real pain to learn but sounds like you're getting the hang of it quite quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work with ids but does work with classes is that ids will override because they are more 'specific'.

When faced with conflicts, CSS order of precedence includes how specifically the style matches the element and ids are the most specific you can get.

Is there a reason you don't want to just use classes?  In the semantic web, classes would generally be favored as way to handle this very situation.

Comment: I suspected it may have something to do with specificity. The only real reason I was trying to avoid using classes was because I'd have a class for each button. As I understood it, unique items should be defined using id's. I guess I'm missing something. Either way, I'll take your advice. Thanks for your help! Leon

Comment: If you are going to interact with the elements with javascript, then there is a performance gain using ids, but for just CSS styling, class definitions are fine.

Comment: Funny you should mention it - my next question was going to be: how do I get the buttons to stay active after they're clicked? I'm thinking it might require some javascript. Am I better off asking that question on a separate thread?